# cannot add nuget dependency 'because of constraints in package.config'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core 2.2 Helix project, where I need to add a dependency to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` 2.2.8.
But when I attempt to add it, I get the following output:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.2.1.0' with respect to project '2_Feature\Personalization\Seges.SC.Feature.Personalization', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1'
Gathering dependency information took 16,76 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.2.1.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the existing packages.config file. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: (...)
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.2.1.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.2.1.0'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.2.1.0' does not exist in project 'Seges.SC.Feature.Personalization'
Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.2.1.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\KVP\Landbrugsinfo\Code\Src\Seges.SC\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 517 ms
Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:17.7218615
```

I looked in my `package.config` and can't really decipher what the issue should be, I cant find anything about any of these being conflicting?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" version="2.9.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer" version="2.9.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers" version="2.9.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NetCore.Analyzers" version="2.9.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NetFramework.Analyzers" version="2.9.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Nito.AsyncEx.Context" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Seges.SC.ProjectSetup" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Kernel" version="9.1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="StyleCop.Analyzers" version="1.1.1-rc.94" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="StyleCop.Analyzers.Unstable" version="1.1.1.94" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.IO.Pipelines" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Emit" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Channels" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Other than that, the output also says something about ``ou are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework` This doesnt make any sense to me, why would this, super standard dotnet package not be compatible with this this very common dotnet framework?

What's the issue here? does it have something to do with the version? or should I perhaps change this file?

Comment: None of `core` libraries are compatible with `framework`. These are completely different versions of .net

Answer (score 0):

You can't add this package since the minimal framework requirement for it is `.NETCoreApp 2.2`. So, it's not compatible with your project.
You can learn more about different target frameworks and their compatibility following these links:

- [.NET architectural components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/components)
- [.NET class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/class-libraries)
- [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)